# Are we able show Violcity Component from Custom Lightning Web Component?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, omnichannel, omni-supervisor, omnistudio

I have a requirement to show an already built OmniScript/FlexCards Component inside a Custom LWC, Custom LWC that has a few buttons, when we click on the button it will show Omni component on the same LWC page, I'm wondering Is that possible?

I'm entirely new to OmniScript.

I saw a few videos about how to call LWC inside OmniScript but not the other way around..

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can embed the OmniScript LWC into your own LWC by referencing the tag of the element, `c-type-subtype-language`.

```
 <c-es-search-products-english prefill={prefill}></c-es-search-products-english>
```

Prefill is an attribute you can use to pass data into the OmniScript dataJson

Comment: This prefill attribute is bit fishy, it works well when using "Managed package runtime", but never works when you disable it.